# Data migration solution between Aurora Postgres and DynamoDb

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

We are in the process of refactoring our databases. As part of that we have modified split our data which used to exist in single Postgres table into a new Postgres table schema and DynamoDB tables. What is the best way to migrate the data from the old schema into this new hybrid schema? We are thinking of writing a Java program to do it. But wanted to check if we can leverage some AWS offering to do this in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AWS Database Migration Service.

> AWS Database Migration Service helps you migrate databases to AWS quickly and securely. The source database remains fully operational during the migration, minimizing downtime to applications that rely on the database. The AWS Database Migration Service can migrate your data to and from most widely used commercial and open-source databases.

See https://aws.amazon.com/dms/